# How can I hide all code before my function header on the same line as it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, comments, hide, outline

I was looking at the code of C# to create Lists and I noticed they were able to hide, not only comments, but anything else occurring before the function header. On top of this, it was collapsed without a preview, just three dots, on the same line as the function header to conserve space. This is perfect, because I want to conserve space but still have detail comments.

On their code, it was nothing more than:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Comment
    //     Comment
    public List()
```

I had copied and pasted what they had done, but go no results.
How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show some code or link for reference ?

Comment: I didn't have enough rep to post the picture in the question, [but here it is](http://i.imgur.com/qTzL2ST.jpg).

Edit: Spelling and grammar.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I didn't know the correct answer after you uploaded the image.

Comment: Okay, well thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Whoever wrote C#. I had looked at their code for the List<T>, using an add in, a believe it's called productivity tools, where you can control click on a function or field and it will bring you to the definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can collapse all your code and then stand on your function header and choose to toggle outlining expansion.

To achieve the described behavior do:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>+ <kbd>O</kbd>  for collapses all definitions

Then stand on your function and click  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to toggle outlining expansion for it.

Here is the result:

[image: Hide code before your method]

Comment: Yes, of course. But where and how does the shown format get created??

Comment: I know this. But what I'm talking about is having comments, or other such things above a function, such as a [Serializable] tag, that all get collapsed onto the same line as the function header, in only three dots, no preview of what it says. [This is the final result](http://i.imgur.com/qTzL2ST.jpg). The open comments are resulted from expanded anyone of the three dots in front of the function headers.

Comment: Is this vs extension can assist you?
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/03141ea7-c35e-4533-b05b-9e60545e93eb